# gif Animated files not loading in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have a windows form application( c# ) and it does multiple things with background worker and lot many threads. Long story short, I published the application using click once. I have throbbers( animated images, gif files ) in the application and I am using pictureBox.ImageLocation to upload the pictures. It is working fine in my system. But, whenever somebody else is installing the application, the .gif images do not show up in their system. The static images are shown properly even though I have used the same function in c# to upload them. Can anybody help me out with what exactly is happening out here and how to go about it?

Comment: "Can anybody help me out with what exactly is happening out here and how to go about it?" We cannot really help you without your code... Nay, we don't even know your problem without it...

Comment: where on your system do  you store the gifs..? are they hard coded paths..? if so then this is your issue.. try using Resource File

Comment: Are these gifs _the same files_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the client computer does not have the files you require on **your** local harddrive.

You of course have to copy the images from your drive / the resource folder to the clients pc.

You should think about making the images embed -- and then setting the images not from your local drive but from `Properties.Resources`